# Notation for a specific unit having a value?

Tags: notation

**Problem:**

> Prove that there are no positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that
>   $$x^2 + 5y = 243,723$$

**Question:**

As far as i can tell i am supposed to prove it by showing that for any value of $x$ then $x^2$ cant have a $3$ as the unit, and neither can $5y$ therefore the sum of $x$ and $y$ will not have 3 as an integer. However i know those statements are true, i do not know how to prove them, can i simply state: $$P(x) = (x|x \mbox{ does not have }3\mbox{ as a unit})$$$$\forall x\in \Bbb{Z^{+}}P(x^2)$$ and $$\forall y \in \Bbb{Z^{+}}P(5y)$$
$$\therefore \forall x\in \Bbb{Z^{+}}(\forall y\in \Bbb{Z^{+}}P(x^2 + 5y)) $$
Is there some notation for a specific unit not having a value? Also the conclusion seems very unecessary should i just have it as text? Just for context this is a part of a step question.

Comment: You mean $3$ in the units digit? That'd be $x \not\equiv 3 \pmod {10}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Just realised that - I missed the forall. I meant that it was probably best to wrap the forall quantifier in brackets

Comment: Writing things with symbolic quantifiers is certainly overkill here; it will obfuscate your proof rather than make it easier to read. Use ordinary prose!

Comment: Also, what if $x^2$ has 6 as the units digit, and $5y$ has $7$ as the units digit? Of course, that's not actually possible, but the line of reasoning your proof gives leaves loopholes such as that open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be expressed using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). The statement you're after is

$$x \not\equiv 3 \pmod {10}$$

I would also explicitly write out something along the lines 'Let $P(x)$ be the statement', but as has already been mentioned in the above comments - doing that isn't necessary, and does indeed obfuscate the proof making it harder to read.

Also I'd suggest wrapping the 'for all' quantifier with brackets to make things absolutely clear. Eg. $$(\forall x\in \Bbb{Z^{+}}) P(x^2)$$

---

I also disagree with your line of reasoning.

$$(a \not\equiv 3 \pmod {10})\land (b \not\equiv 3 \pmod {10})$$

does not necessarily imply that their sum cannot be equivalent to $3 \pmod {10}$. What if
$$(a \equiv 6 \pmod {10})\land (b \equiv 7 \pmod {10})$$

---

'Also the conclusion seems very unnecessary should i just have it as text?'

I'm not too sure what you mean by that, but you should always include at the end something expressing 'Therefore, what I've set out to prove is true' for completeness and clarity.

Comment: I read the wiki on modulus arithmetic and i think i understand it however is a proof for $x^2 \not\equiv 3 (\mbox{mod } 10)$ that is simple that you know of, or would this be considered unnecessary in a question for an entrance exam (such as this one)?

Comment: You can simply state $(\forall x\in \mathbb Z)\,\, x^2 \not\equiv 3 \pmod{10}$, as it is well known that no squares end in 3. To prove it, you can prove $x^2\not\equiv3\pmod5$ (case by case proof is acceptable here) which implies $x^2 \not\equiv 3 \pmod{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exists x ~:~ x^2 = 243723 \pmod 5$$

You only have to check 5 values.

---

Without using prerolled modular arithmetic, if there is an $y$ such that $x^2 + 5y = 243723$ then there is a $z$ such that $x^2 + 5z = 3$ using $z = y - 243720 / 5$.

Second, if there is a $z$ such that $x^2 + 5z = 3$ then there is an $w$ such that $(x - 5)^2 + 5w = z$, using $5z = 5w + 10x + 25$.

So you only need to check any consecutive $5$ values of $x$ and see if it is possible that $x^2 - 3$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: technically if y is even x^2 must be $3\equiv \pmod{10}$ .But if y is odd $x^2\equiv 8 \pmod {10} $ neither of which exist in the integers.